# amd display driver crash in Windows 10 version 1607

Tags: freeze, crash, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1511, amd-graphics-card

I am facing this problem from the first version of windows 10. Initially, the error was: "amd Display driver stopped responding and has recovered". I searched solutions at [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-error-display-driver-has-stopped/8f4302b9-4710-4fb3-aad3-6eb8edd2c479) about this issue. The solutions they provided didn't work for me.There are lots of threads about it at where different type of solutions have been suggested. I tried with many methods such as:

- Update amd driver & all other drivers
- Used old amd drivers  (some latest versioned amd drivers generate this issue continuously where some old version generate this less quickly than some latest versions).
- Update Intel Drivers
- Uninstall display drivers and let windows to choose automatically the stable drivers.
- [TDR fix](https://community.amd.com/thread/180166)

Unfortunately, none of those worked for me. After updating to windows anniversary update, that error message (amd Display driver stopped...) never shows but the issue still exists! Still, it fully freezes at the time of performing different tasks i.e. browsing, watching video, playing game etc. Sometimes, freezing has been solved automatically after 1-2 seconds. But, sometime it's not fixed automatically so that I have to force shut down by pressing the power button of the PC.

Now, I have found some threads at where people tell that they are facing this freezing issue only after updating to Windows Anniversary Update. One of those threads is: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4vufpo/windows_10_fully_freezes_after_anniversary_update

But, I have faced this since I used old version of Windows 10 at my brand new PC. PC Configuration:

- Intel Processor Core i7 3.6 GHZ 4th GEN
- GigabyteB85 Chipset Motherboard GA-B85M-D3H
- Graphics Card MSI R7 260X 2GBD5 OCV3
- Gaming RAM G-Skill Tridentx 16GB (8*2) DDR3 1600 BUS CL10 1.65V
- HDD 1TB Western Digital SATA 7200 RPM WD
- Gaming Power Supply Corsair VS500

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vNk6Xvh.png]

I am very frustrated with this issue now. Is there anyone who has faced all those issue and solved successfully?

Comment: try the driver 16.9.1 : http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Crimson-Edition-16-9-1-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am 90% sure that this version won't fix the issue. I have tried with every versions whenever they released. At maximum release notes, they said that it would fix crash issue. But, it didn't. But, still I will try with this version as you've suggested.

Comment: try the driver. you use 15.11 driver which is 10 months old

Comment: I have installed the new driver (16.9.1). And as expected, it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: post some HW specs and which PSU you use.

Comment: I have edited question by adding HW specs

Comment: put the GPU into the other PCIe x16 slot eveb if this only runs at x4 speed.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: not solved. By the way, I have returned to the previous version of amd driver. Latest one was making it worst.

Comment: have you tried the other PCIe slot?

Comment: yes, I tried. Actually, it's not my software/hardware issue-I believe. There are lots of people facing this issue. If you take a look on the links of those threads which I gave at my post, you'll understand that.

Comment: I never had the issue since the TDR was added in Vista

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem since updating to Win10 v1607 (Anniversary Update). I have had the exact same symptoms on 2 identical machines with Nvidia cards, each driving 4 monitors. It's so frustrating because it happens without warning! I asked a friend about it several months ago, and several exchanges later I finally got in touch with some GPU devs. They think it's something related to TDR.

I haven't tried this (my machine is attached to a kernel debugger as we speak), but you might want to give this a try for a workaround. It involves increasing the `TdrDiDelay` value (in addition to `TdrDelay`, which you pointed out in your question):
https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/4y4202/for_those_of_you_having_frame_freezing_or_driver/

The keys are explained on MSDN here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918(v=vs.85).aspx

As for a real solution, it sounds like a driver or hardware problem and you might want to try and contact MSI or AMD. Maybe offer them to attach a kernel debugger and/or take memory dumps of your machine and fix their drivers. Or, if your card is under warranty, maybe get a replacement and see if it still happens.

Comment: The author specifically says they tried the TDR fix.  Your answers sort of fails to recognize this fact and honestly fails to answer the question.  Even worst you did point out the author tried the TDR fix yet you suggested anyways.

Comment: I actually mentioned it in my answer ("in addition to TdrDelay, which you pointed out in your question") The OP linked to a page discussing the TdrDelay registry setting. However, the link I provided also describes the TdrDiDelay registry setting, which is different.